# Which metal bicarbonates do not exist in solid state?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

$$\ce{(i) LiHCO_3       (ii) Ca(HCO_3)_2 ​      (iii) Zn(HCO_3)_2 ​     (iv) AgHCO_3}$$
From my prior knowledge compounds i and ii are not solids because of the high hydration energy of Li and the high polarizing power of Ca respectively. But the answer to this question includes both options iii and iv. Which property makes them not solid/exist in solution state?

Comment: Regarding LiHCO3, see these questions: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73575/is-lithium-bicarbonate-an-aqueous-solution-of-lithium-carbonate .... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69331/why-doesnt-lihco3-exist-in-solid-state/69556

Comment: Too bad your teacher forgot to give you his list that you can learn by heart. What a moronic multiple choice question.

Comment: The only existing carbonate at the solid state is LiHCO3.

Comment: @Maurice LiHCO3 does not exist in solid state

Comment: @Singularity. The Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, 43 rd Ed, p. 597, informs that LiHCO3 is white and its solubility is 5.5 g in 100 mL water at 13°C.

Comment: @Maurice for some reason the solution to this question states all of these don't exist in solid form and some of my friends (who didn't give me a reason) implied the same. Ps- Maybe i got bad friends Xd Thanks for the help

Comment: @Singuilarity. Or maybe my Handbook was wrong. Who knows ?

Comment: @Maurice I didn't mean to imply that, sorry, i was just saying what i knew.Btw thanks for that reference book that seems quite useful for my purposes.

Comment: @Singularity. Well. The Handbook of Chemistry and Physics is a must for all students and professionals in chemistry. It has more than 2000 pages. And it is not too expensive, because it is reprinted every year, and so many people are buying it. It can also be found on the net.